# Copy cell data and paste on different ranges based on date

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Hi I'm extremely new to this and I would like to seek assistance with my code.

Please see my code below:

```
Sub Copy_Cells_Loop()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Range("B1").Value = "8/1/2017" Then Worksheets("Dispute").Range("C2:C76").Value = Range("H9:H83").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So what i'm looking for is that if the value of B1 changed from 8/1/2017 to 8/2/2017, the date will be paste to another worksheet to a different range. Please help me. :(

Comment: Use an `Else` clause in your `If` statement - `If Range("B1").Value = DateSerial(2017,8,1) Then ... Else ...` or, if you have several possible conditions, use a multi-line `If` (i.e. `If ... Then` `...` `ElseIf ... Then` `...` `ElseIf ... Then` `...` `Else` `...` `End If`) or a `Select Case Range("B1").Value` block.

Comment: Don't forget to end your `If` statements with `End If`, always!

Comment: @dwirony Not on single-line `If` statements, only on multi-line ones.

Comment: @YowE3K Wow, I didn't even know you could do that... I always figured that was just bad formatting. Looks like I'm still an excel noob!

Comment: @dwirony LOL - we are **all** Excel noobs !!

Comment: As you have it now, the code will copy the range specified only if B1 equals 8/1/2017. But in your question you seem to want the range copied if B1 equals 8/2/2017 -- is that just a typo?

Comment: Apart from using `Else` conditions on the `If`, if there is any pattern to what worksheet / range needs to be updated on the different dates, it might be possible to calculate the worksheet name based on the date (e.g. if the sheet was "Dispute 01" on the 1st of the month and "Dispute 02" on the 2nd of the month, you could use `Worksheets("Dispute " & Format(Range("B1").Value, "dd")).Range...`) and avoid the `If` altogether.